# Set a field to invalid state so form cannot submit using HTML5?

Tags: html, forms, validation, input, submit

In a field using HTML5 I can set the required attribute and it will not submit the form unless it's filled.

```
<input id="first_name" name="user[first_name]" required type="text" value="">
```

Is there an attribute I can add to an input element that prevents the form from submitting even if there is something inside it?

Something like:

```
<input id="first_name" name="user[first_name]" required invalid="true" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Depends on the browser. http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Basically required only works to check if something is written inside. I want to just set it as invalid regardless of content. For example, the name is not valid.

Comment: I understand now.  Could you explain what use case you're trying to handle?  I assume you don't want to use javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern like example below which won't send the form until input field is not equal 'text'

```
<input id="first_name" type="text" name="user[first_name]" required pattern="^((?!text).)*$" value="text">
```